# Maven deploy without <parent> tag

Tags: java, maven, jar

Project structure:

```
src
- pom.xml (parent POM)
- core (lot of folders, sub-folders, source files)
- deploy
    - DTO
    - pom.xml
```

The DTO folder:

- uses shade plugin to collect a few classes from core and create a new jar
- this new jar has simple POJOs and does not need any dependencies
- hence the deployed POM for this jar should not have any parent or dependencies as this jar is used by many other clients (android is one)
- however, since the POM in DTO folder is inherited from the parent pom, this parent inheritence is an issue

**Question:** how can we deploy this jar with a simplified custom POM without any parent?

**Possible solution:** DTO POM can be without parent. However, we lose many inheritences, such as version, properties, repository etc., which need to be redefined in the DTO POM if it does not have any parent.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The parent pom is not visible in at runtime. So there is no Problem if you use a jar  in other environments

Comment: The DTO pom.xml that is deployed to maven has the parent tag. When android app uses this DTO  jar as dependency, it will also look for the parent pom which pulls in the dependencies - which wont be available in android. Hence the build fails. What did you mean iparent pom is not visible?

Comment: a parent.pom should not have any dependencies. You should restructure your project

Comment: how is that possible? the parent pom defines all common dependencies used by all the sources in the project.

Comment: It only shoud have a section <DependencyManagememt>. Which defines what artefact with which Version should beused.

Comment: And the modules should have the dependencies section

Comment: not a good idea. then the dependencies are replicated in all modules.

Comment: Yes but only this which are used by the module

Comment: the project here is very complex. i dont that solution would work well.

Comment: It is working well and makes your dependency hierachy much more transparent